# Finding the minimum value of $X+Y$ given inputs $A$ and $B$ and some constraints

Tags: number-theory, inequality, optimization

The problem is to find the minimum value of $X+Y$ given some value of $A$ and $B$ and the constraint that $$(A+X)\ \big|\ (B+Y)$$ and $X,Y \ge 0$.

This was given as a coding problem, but I want to see if this has a solution without using code.

First we know that $(B+Y) = k(A+X)$ for some integer $k \ge 1$. If $A\ | \ B$ then trivially $X=0=Y$ works. Otherwise, taking into consideration that $Y\ge 0$, we get the bound $$k(A+X) \ge B$$
Also from the fact that minimizing $X+Y$ is the same as minimizing $X+Y+A+B = (k+1)(A+X)$. Since $X,Y\ge 0$ this gives us $$(k+1)(A+X) \ge A+B$$
From this we tried the "trivial" thing $$ k = \max\left\{\lceil \sqrt{A+B}-1\rceil,\lceil\sqrt B\rceil\right\}$$
$$ X = \max\left\{\lceil \sqrt{A+B}-A\rceil,\lceil\sqrt B-A\rceil\right\}$$
But this does not work, as it gives a large value for $X+Y$ or $X$ becomes negative. For an example where this fails:

Let $A = 4394, B = 993298361$. This gives us a minimum value of $X+Y$ as $65$ with $X=25, Y=40$. I'm at a loss on how to proceed. Any help is appreciated. Here are some more values of $A$ and $B$ with the expected minimum value of $X+Y$.

| $A$ | $B$ | $X+Y$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $11$ | $23$ | $2$ |
| $8$ | $16$ | $0$ |
| $4394$ | $993298361$ | $65$ |
| $95392025$ | $569922442$ | $2429708$ |
| $8399283$ | $10293$ | $8388990$ |

Comment: Can you credit the source where you encountered this problem?

Comment: I got this problem from a friend of mine